# Laravel getting 403 Forbidden error "You don't have permission to access this resource."

Tags: php, laravel, apache, mamp

i am working on a Laravel project in MAMP environment.

Basically, if i created Laravel project in

```
/User/my-user/Desktop/myLaravelProj
```

when i go http://localhost, browser shows me 403 Forbidden error "You don't have permission to access this resource."

And if i moved Laravel  project to

```
/Users/my-user/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/myLaravelProj or /Library/WebServer/Documents/myLaravelProj
```

It works fine.

I've changed `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`'s `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` to `corresponding-directory/myLaravelProj/public` when i moved my project folder around. I also granted permission for directories storage and bootstrap/cache by

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage/ bootstrap/cache/
sudo chown -R my-user:www storage/ bootstrap/cache/
```

I like to have my Laravel project in Desktop for quicker access. Anything i missed out?

Comment: Welcome SO ..  what u want to achieve or u want suggestion .?

Comment: i would like to have my working project in Desktop without having an 403 Forbidden permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` add this

```xml
<Directory "/desktopFolderPath"> // here your dir path
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: i works in MAMP environment, but i don't have MAMP application, i install Apache, Mysql and PHP individually. May i know which file should i change?

Comment: i do have this in my code.
DocumentRoot "/Users/my-user/Desktop/links/public"
<Directory "/Users/my-user/Desktop/links/public">
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>. And i also restart apache service after this. But it gives same result. I do the same for other directory path, and it works.